# Jquery addClass / removeClass click issue

Tags: jquery, if-statement, click, addclass, removeclass

Can't get this jQuery working. The code is available here:

http://jsfiddle.net/PuXDN/14/

I can't get to change the color on "Graphc Design" link  once i clicked the "Web Design" link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you want something more like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $linkWeb = $("#link-web-design");
    var $linkGraphic = $("#link-graphic-design");

    $linkWeb.click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("colorText")) {
            $(this).removeClass("colorText");
            $linkGraphic.addClass("colorText");
        }                
    });

    $linkGraphic.click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("colorText")) {
            $(this).removeClass("colorText");
            $linkWeb.addClass("colorText");
        }           
    });
});​
```

?

http://jsfiddle.net/Grimdotdotdot/PuXDN/19/

Answer (score 0):

This can also highlight only the last clicked link:

```js
function arct(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // optional
    $('a').removeClass('colorText');
    $(this).addClass("colorText");
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#link-web-design").click(arct);
    $("#link-graphic-design").click(arct);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PuXDN/20/